# QDataStream and QByteArray wirh ByteOrder

Tags: c++, qt

I met a question recently when I want to fill a QByteArray type with QDataStream. QDataStream can set Byteorder.

```
uint16_t data[2] = {10, 20};
QByteArray array;
QDataStream in(&array, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_7);
in.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);
in.writeRawData((char*)data, 4);
qDebug()<<(int)array[0]<<(int)array[1]<<(int)array[2]<<(int)array[3];
```

This code output on the below:

```
10 0 20 0
```

If I change the ByteOrder from  BigEndian to LittleEndian, the output is same. Why I change the ByteOrder and receive the same result? What I think the output should like below:

```
0 10 0 20
```

If I want to get reverse result, how should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writeRawData` is not what you are looking for, it just appends the data to buffer as is. Endianness depends on the type but `writeRawData` takes parameter as `char*` so it doesn't know anything about the type that you want to serialize.

The possible implementation at below. 
Prints the buffer in hexadecimal representation.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QByteArray>

int main()
{
    QByteArray buffer;
    QDataStream ss { &buffer , QIODevice::ReadWrite };

    uint16_t data[2] = {10, 20};
    QByteArray array_be;
    QDataStream in_be(&array_be, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    in_be.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_7);
    in_be.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);

    in_be << data[ 0 ] << data [ 1 ];

    qDebug() << "BE :" << array_be.toHex( ' ' );

    QByteArray array_le;
    QDataStream in_le(&array_le, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    in_le.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_7);
    in_le.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);

    in_le << data[ 0 ] << data [ 1 ];

    qDebug() << "LE :" << array_le.toHex( ' ' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know why writeRawData doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
in.writeRawData((char*)data, 4);
```

you are writing 4 `char` objects. The outcome of that operation doesn't change no matter which endianness you use. Use

```
in << data[0] << data[1]
```

instead.